Which flag should i add in RPC node
Hello guys i was wondering in order for getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner method to work as a request through my RPC node what flag should i add? I only added:
--account-index spl-token-owner
--account-index spl-token-mint
But it seems its not enough, do i need to enable --account-index program-id as well? or is there any other flag for that.
We all know that there is not detailed docs for that so hopefuly some of you knows, thanks in advance
